# How do I check the amount of memory my program uses in vista's task manager?

Tags: windows-vista, task-manager

The columns in xp's task manager differ from the ones in vista/7 and that's why I'm asking that question.Which column in vista's task manager shows the amount of memory that a program had allocated?

Comment: Check: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx, http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/replacing-task-manager-with-process-explorer-in-vista/ too...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Memory column under the processes tab... Same as XP if I understand your question correctly.

Edit: Misunderstood your question. Here's a rundown of what each memory column does from [Windows Help](http://windowshelp.microsoft.com/Windows/en-US/help/e4598b92-b1c1-bc52-5e30-6871dcc59ca01033.mspx).

- **Memory - Working Set** - Amount of memory in the private working set plus the amount of memory the process is using that can be shared by other processes.
- **Memory - Peak Working Set** - Maximum amount of working set memory used by the process.
- **Memory - Working Set Delta** - Amount of change in working set memory used by the process.
- **Memory - Private Working Set** - Subset of working set that specifically describes the amount of memory a process is using that cannot be shared by other processes.
- **Memory - Commit Size** - Amount of virtual memory that is reserved for use by a process.
- **Memory - Paged Pool** - Amount of committed virtual memory for a process that can be written to another storage medium, such as the hard disk.
- **Memory - Non-paged Pool** - Amount of committed virtual memory for a process that cannot be written to another storage medium.

Probably Commit Size you're looking for?

Comment: The column I needed while using XP is not the default one,which you described.It's named 'virtual memory size'.But in vista the columns have totally different names.

Comment: @John, it's under View -> Select Columns

Comment: You misunderstood me.I know where the columns are located at,but I don't know the name of that particular column "VM Size" in Vista's task manager.

Comment: Yes,thanks for the edit,I found it at support.microsoft - unbelievable.

Comment: I doubt he's looking for commit size. That measures virtual memory (address space) usage, and virtual memory is not really a scarce resource.