# My Windows 7 64-bit is reluctant to use all 8GB. Why?

Tags: memory, dell-precision

The computer recognizes all 8GBs of RAM. When using some memory hogging applications, the computer would barely pass 4GBs of usage.

Things I've tried:

- I reseated the sticks with not much luck.
- There is no "maximum memory" flag set in msconfig.
- There is no "memory remapping" option in the BIOS.
- I've updated the BIOS to the latest version.

I have 4 x 2GB sticks (DDR2 PC2-5300 ECC) in this Dell Precision T5400 workstation. The 2 recently added sticks are x4 organization and the original are x8. I'm not sure if that would make a difference.

Comment: Which OS are you using (specifically thinking of a 32bit or 64 bit OS since two memory hogging 32 bit applications would be more of less limited to 2GB each).

Comment: Note that it doesn't matter so much what the OS is, it matters what the applications are.  32-bit applications are limited to 2GB memory space in Windows in pretty much all circumstances, even on a 64-bit operating system.  (Of course, if you're running a 32-bit operating system there's your problem right there...)  There's also no guarantee that your software needs that much anyway!

Comment: Also, just because the "memory hogging" applications dont go above 4GB, doesnt mean they *need* to go above 4GB.

Comment: I should have mentioned that, most of the applications are Java based (i.e. Eclipse & Tomcat). They are running at 64-bit.

Comment: A colleague's computer with similar specs and just running eclipse and some web browsers will be floating around 5.5GBs. He has 8GBs as well.

Comment: Make sure you allow the JVM to take this much RAM. Look into heap-size related JVM arguments like `-Xmx` and how to specify those for your applications.

Comment: it sounds to me like you dont have a problem at all...

Comment: In the Task Manager the computer won't pass an imaginary threshold of 4GBs. Leads me to believe the computer prefers to use swap over memory. I could run 20 applications and it will still float around that number.

Comment: Incorrect, task manager would still report the program as "using" the memory even if the data was stored in swap. See [this SU answer](http://superuser.com/questions/27863/how-do-i-check-the-amount-of-memory-my-program-uses-in-vistas-task-manager/27865#27865) explaining what the terms mean

Comment: Thanks @ScottChamberlain for the info! It's quite useful but doesn't answer why "Physical Memory Usage History" graph sits at 50%. From my understanding, in the Linux world your memory should be used all the time and things are pushed to swap when needed. Windows is opting for slower HDD when there is still 50% of physical memory left.